# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid pks [10] - unknown typecode 0

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to fire Flexible Search Query from DAO layer. My query is something like:

```
SELECT {loyaltypoints},{redeemedloyaltypoints}  
FROM {LoyaltyUser} 
WHERE {uid} =?uid
```

is throwing me unknown type code but my type code is proper. I see the stack trace message like

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DispatcherServlet] in context with path [/store]
threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
    invalid pks [10] - unknown typecode 0] with root cause
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid pks [10] - unknown typecode 0
    at de.hybris.platform.core.WrapperFactory.getCachedItems(WrapperFactory.java:304)
    at de.hybris.platform.core.LazyLoadItemList.loadPage(LazyLoadItemList.java:230)
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.impl.LazyLoadModelList.loadPage(LazyLoadModelList.java)"
```

My `items.xml` looks like:

```
<itemtype code="LoyaltyUser" extends="Customer" autocreate="true" generate="true"
    jaloclass="de.hybris.merchandise.core.jalo.LoyaltyUser">
    <deployment table="LoyaltyUsers" typecode="10010"/>
    <attributes>
        <attribute generate="true" autocreate="true" qualifier="loyaltypoints" type="java.lang.Integer" >
            &ltdescription&gtLoyalty points given for each purchase&lt/description&gt
            <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true" />
            <defaultvalue>Integer.valueOf(0)</defaultvalue>
            <persistence type="property"/>
        </attribute>
        <attribute generate="true" autocreate="true" qualifier="redeemedloyaltypoints" type="java.lang.Integer" >
            <description>Redeemed Loyalty points For a customer</description>
            <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true" />
            <defaultvalue>Integer.valueOf(0)</defaultvalue>
            <persistence type="property"/>
        </attribute>
    </attributes>
</itemtype>
```

Could anyone help me out from this issue?

Comment: did you try debugging this? Could you provide the full flexible query string?
What is your return type of the query? If you expect instances of LoyaltyUser back, you might have to include {pk} in order to get back the actual LoyaltyUser item back, right now you only select two Integers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than getting two attribute `{loyaltypoints}`,`{redeemedloyaltypoints}` in query, you should get PK of your `LoyaltyUser` Model.

`SELECT {pk} FROM {LoyaltyUser} WHERE {uid} =?uid`

Query will give LoyaltyUserModel then you can get its attribute by getter method.

```
Integer loyalyPoint = loyaltyUserModel.getLoyaltypoints()
Integer redeemedLoyaltyPoint = loyaltyUserModel.getRedeemedloyaltypoints()
```

Comment: It's working fine after adding pk in flexi search, but what would be reason to add the pk here.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to do it , although you will require String manipulation

```
 StringBuilder queryString=new StringBuilder();
    queryString.append("SELECT CONCAT({loyaltypoints},CONCAT('|'{redeemedloyaltypoints}))FROM {LoyaltyUser} WHERE {uid} =?uid");
    FlexibleSearchQuery query = new FlexibleSearchQuery(queryString);
    
    query.addQueryParameter("uid", uid);
    query.setResultClassList(Collections.singletonList(String.class));
    final SearchResult<String> result = getFlexibleSearchService().search(query);
    return result.getResult();
```

The result will look like list of values **loyaltypoints | redeemedloyaltypoints** and then you can split the string and get the values.